# fibonacci numbers start 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 for options 2, but how do i start for option 3 or 4

Tags: php, fibonacci

I am trying to code the codility les 13 ladder.php exercise.
You have to calc using the fibonacci numers the total ways you can climb a ladder when you can do 1 or 2 rungs at the time.

I made a loop creating the first 50 fibonacci numbers like this:

```
$total = 50;
$fibonacci[0]=0;
$fibonacci[1]=1;
for($i=2;$i<=$total;$i++){
    $fibonacci[$i] = $fibonacci[($i-1)] + $fibonacci[($i-2)];
}
```

This works well if you can do 1 or 2 rungs at the time.

But how do i adjust this loop to give me the first 50 fibonacci numbers if you can take 1, 2 or 3 rungs at the time.

if you can take 1 or 2 rungs you use: `Fx = F[(x-1)] + F[(x-2)];`

if you can do 1, 2 and 3 you use: `Fx = F[(x-1)] + F[(x-2)] + F[(x-3)];`

if you can do 1, 2, 3 and 4 you use: `Fx = F[(x-1)] + F[(x-2)] + F[(x-3)] + F[(x-4)];`

Then you can make as many numbers or calculate as many numbers as you wish.
But you always need the first few numbers to be able to make the calculations.

I hope this table makes clear what i mean:

```
    2   3   4   5   6
1   1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2   2
3   3   4   4   4   4
4   5   7   8   8   8
5   8   13  15  16  16
6   13  24  29  31  32
```

The row below 2 is the basic fibonacci

Below 3 I would need number 1 to 3 to be able to calculate #4 and so on

Below 4 I need the first 4 to be able to calc #5 and so on

Can anyone help me create a loop to create the first say 10 numbers for row 4 and 5 and 6?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm... I read your question 2 times and still I don't get you

Comment: if you check the table, the first row of number is the fibonacci sequence wich you can start with 0,1 and then calculate the other numbers using f[(x-1)} = f[(x-2)].

Comment: that gives you the basic 1,2,3,5,8....

Comment: the second row under 3 is if you can climb the lader using 1 2 or 3 rungs at the time, there are diverent starting results, as you have more options to pick climbing the ladder.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a function returns a part of fibonacci numbers. You can set a start element (0 - based) and how many elements you need.

```
function takeFibonacci($start, $length)
{
    $fibonacci = array(0, 1);
    $result = array();

    $position = 0;
    do {
        if (!isset($fibonacci[$position])) {
            $fibonacci[$position] = $fibonacci[$position - 1] + $fibonacci[$position - 2];      
        }

        if ($position >= $start) {
            $result[] = $fibonacci[$position];
        }

        $position++;
    } while ($position < $start + $length);

    return $result;
}

$fib = takeFibonacci(5, 5);
var_dump($fib);
```

Code above returns this result

> array(5) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(8) [2]=> int(13) [3]=> int(21) [4]=> int(34) }